# Is Redis list or set pop method thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, redis

I'm building out a queuing service which will be multi-threaded. I need to make sure that Redis, our data backend, has a thread safe pop function for either lists or set types. The idea being that any number of threads can invoke Redis `lpop` or `spop` and not have any collisions. I'm not really sure how to test this and it doesn't explicitly state anywhere on the Redis page if the pop function is thread-safe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

from [the benchmark page](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks)

> Redis is a single-threaded server. It is not designed to benefit from
>   multiple CPU cores. People are supposed to launch several Redis
>   instances to scale out on several cores if needed. It is not really
>   fair to compare one single Redis instance to a multi-threaded data
>   store.

so as every command gets queued in a single thread you should be ok as there will never be two commands executing in parallel